# File not attaching to email in powershell script

Tags: powershell, azure-powershell

I am creating a CSV file and trying to attach it to an email.  Also doing this in the cloud so I want to bypass local drives...just create the file and attach it.  But I'm getting this error...

You cannot call a method on a null-valued expression.  At line:67 char:1 $smtp.Attachments.Add($att.Name)

Am I not attaching it the right way? The email is sending but with no attachment. I know it's being created because when I put it in an Azure container I can see it.  But I want to do this without storing it first.  This seems right. Thank you!

```
$SqlAdapter.Fill($DataSet)
$att = New-Item filename.csv -ItemType file
$DataSet.Tables[0] | Export-CSV -NoTypeInformation $att
$smtp = New-Object System.Net.Mail.SmtpClient($SMTPServer, $SMTPPort)
$smtp.Credentials = New-Object System.Net.NetworkCredential($Username, $Password)  
$smtp.Attachments.Add($att)
$smtp.Send($From, $To, $subject, $body)
```

Comment: The smtpclient class expects an attachment object, you are feeding a filesystem object to it. I would also use Send-MailMessage to send mails if I were you (instead of using the SmtpClient class)

Answer (score 1, accepted):

The SmtpClient class will want an `Net.Mail.Attachment` object:

```
$att = New-Object Net.Mail.Attachment($file)
```

Any reason you're building out objects instead of using the `Send-MailMessage` cmdlet?

```
Send-MailMessage -To $To -From $From -Subject $Subject -Body $Body -SmtpServer $SmtpServer -Attachments $PathToAttachment
```

Comment: Not necessarily. If you give it just a filename it will assume a path relative to the current working directory per usual.

Comment: Yes I will try to transition to the Send-MailMessage cmdlet to make this simpler.